# How do you add buttons to a jQuery datepicker in the button panel?

Tags: jquery-ui

Do I just append the element to the panel wrapper and call .button()?

Answer (score 46):

If you want to keep the "clear" button while scrolling through the months, use `onChangeMonthYear:`.

An example:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    beforeShow: function( input ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var buttonPane = $( input )
                .datepicker( "widget" )
                .find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );

            $( "<button>", {
                text: "Clear",
                click: function() {
                //Code to clear your date field (text box, read only field etc.) I had to remove the line below and add custom code here
                    $.datepicker._clearDate( input );
                }
            }).appendTo( buttonPane ).addClass("ui-datepicker-clear ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all");
        }, 1 );
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function( year, month, instance ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var buttonPane = $( instance )
                .datepicker( "widget" )
                .find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );

            $( "<button>", {
                text: "Clear",
                click: function() {
                //Code to clear your date field (text box, read only field etc.) I had to remove the line below and add custom code here
                    $.datepicker._clearDate( instance.input );
                }
            }).appendTo( buttonPane ).addClass("ui-datepicker-clear ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all");
        }, 1 );
    }
});
```

Comment: when I keep datepicker open with  $(this).data('datepicker').inline = true; , the custom button and Done button disappear after I select date. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 11):

The following code will allow you to add another button to the jQuery UI datepicker.  Multiple buttons can be added.  You also need to code the OnChangeMonthYear to retain the new buttons as the year/month is changed.  Note - the OnChangeMonthYear accepts a year, month and the input control (a little different from beforeShow).

```
var datePickerOptsMax: {
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: 'Styles/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: 'Select a date',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: 'true',
    changeYear: 'true',
    beforeShow: function (input) { 
        dpClearButton(input);    
        dpMaxButton(input); 
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (yy, mm, inst) { 
        dpClearButton(inst.input); 
        dpMaxButton(inst.input); 
    }
}

function dpClearButton (input) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var buttonPane = $(input)
        .datepicker("widget")
        .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

        $("<button>", {
            text: "Clear",
            click: function () { jQuery.datepicker._clearDate(input); }
        }).appendTo(buttonPane).addClass("ui-datepicker-clear ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all");
    }, 1)
}
function dpMaxButton (input) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var buttonPane = $(input)
        .datepicker("widget")
        .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
        $("<button>", {
            text: "Max",
            click: function () { 
                 jQuery(input).datepicker('setDate', '31-Dec-9999');   
                 jQuery(input).datepicker('hide'); }
        }).appendTo(buttonPane).addClass("ui-datepicker-clear ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all");
    }, 1)
}

jQuery('#txtboxid').dialog(datePickerOptsMax);
```

Answer (score 7):

I saw a post showing how to add a button to this area of the datepicker here:

http://csharptechies.blogspot.com/2010/12/adding-custom-buttons-to-jquery.html

It works ok however, when you change the month, the custom buttons dissappear. Would be very interested to know if anyone managed to keep the buttons visible.

Answer (score 4):

You can change "BeforeShow" attribute of datepicker in your jquery-ui.js file.

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({  
 showButtonPanel: true,  
      beforeShow: function( input ) {  
 setTimeout(function() {  
   var buttonPane = $( input )  
     .datepicker( "widget" )  
     .find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );  
  
   var btn = $('<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all">Clear</button>');  
   btn  
    .unbind("click")  
    .bind("click", function () {  
    $.datepicker._clearDate( input );  
  });  
  
   btn.appendTo( buttonPane );  
  
 }, 1 );  
      }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<input class="datepicker" type="text">
```

Answer (score 3):

This sample code adds a previous day and next day button in the jQuery datepicker in the button panel:

```
//   Setting date picker options.
$('#datepicker').datepicker(
    {    onSelect: newDateSelected,   //function for new date 
         showButtonPanel: true, 
    }
);

//   HTML Text for previous day button
var PrevDay     = '<button id="PrevDay" class="ui-datepicker-current ' + 
              'ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" '+
              'type="button">Prev Day</button> ';
//   HTML Text for next day button
var NextDay     = '<button id="NextDay" class="ui-datepicker-current ' + 
                  'ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" '+
                  'type="button">Next Day</button> ';

//    Setting text for Date Picker Button Panel       
$('#datepicker').datepicker("option", "currentText", "Today " + PrevDay  + NextDay );

//    Setting "click" functions for prev and next day buttons.
$('#NextDay').click(nextDaySelected);
$('#PrevDay').click(prevDaySelected);


//===========Begin Functions==============================
function nextDaySelected(){
    alert("Next Day Selected; button not activated yet.");
}

function prevDaySelected(){
    alert("Previous Day Selected; button not activated yet.");
}

function newDateSelected(dateText, inst){
    // .toSource displays object details in FireFox
    alert("dateText = " + dateText + ", inst = " + inst.toSource());

    //  Timeout was added to re-enable PrevDay and NextDay Buttons.
    setTimeout(function (){
    $('#NextDay').click(nextDaySelected);
    $('#PrevDay').click(prevDaySelected);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about using button/icon for triggering you can use this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
</script>
```

If you want to assign it to a link/button:

```
<script>
$(function() {    
       $(button_id).click(function() {
          $(input).datepicker('show');
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, there is an example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#buttonbar I am talking about the area below the horizontal row.

Comment: This is inside the core. You should be able to track where is the html for it, but that means messing up with the core, and now allowing the plugin to update. You can try to append the button to "ui-datepicker-buttonpane ui-widget-content", but this is a class and not id, so it may not be unique...

Comment: Yeah I think that's what I will end up doing. Thing is, I think they regen their HTML ever time the calendar is updated. So I'd have to attach the element every time using their "beforeShow" event.

Answer (score 0):

I did a JQuery plugin based on the DatePicker to add buttons you can check it on my github:

https://github.com/rogeroliveira84/bootstrap-datepicker-buttons

It adds automatically the buttons: Last month, This week, Yesterday, Today