# How to show the datepicker when a button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to add a custom button to the button panel of jQuery's datepicker. When I apply the following code though nothing happens:

```
 $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,  
        beforeShow: function(input) {  
            setTimeout(function() {  
            var buttonPane = $(input).datepicker("widget").find( ".ui-datepicker-buttonpane" );  
            var btn = $('<button class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">Clear</button>');  
            btn.unbind("click").bind("click", function () {  
                $.datepicker._clearDate( input );  
            });  

            btn.appendTo( buttonPane );  

            }, 1 );  
        } ,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it seems to work here button got added http://jsfiddle.net/HXLk4/6/

Comment: The other formatting disappeared though. I'm not displaying the calendar, just date and month. But all the same, sniff, why not for me? : (

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598850/how-do-you-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-datepicker-in-the-button-panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var pickerOpts = {
        showOn: "button"
    };  
    $("#date").datepicker(pickerOpts);
});
```

Comment: I think this answers the question "How to show the datepicker when a button is clicked?", but the actual question asked is "How to show a custom button on the datepicker once it is already visible?"

Answer (score 1):

A related question "How do you add buttons to a jQuery datepicker in the button panel?" was answered in another post.  For an example of how a "Prev Day" and "Next Day" button was added to the button panel, see [How do you add buttons to a jQuery datepicker in the button panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598850/how-do-you-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-datepicker-in-the-button-panel)