# Skyscanner like Javascript calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm looking for a Skyscanner like Javascript calendar (jQuery powered if possible).
The jQuery UI's one doesn't fit my needs as it's not very flexible.

For instance, I need to add buttons (like Skyscanner) to select the next weekend for example.
Also, I'd like to have them on top of the calendar grid.

[image: Skyscanner Calendar]

I searched a lot recently and found nothing.

Any ideas to share?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Though not jQuery based, I really like and suggest [Kalendae](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae):

[image]

Another one, having all the features (like month and year selection and etc, but not the exact UI) is [JSCal2](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/) though I think it's not completely free - check out their site for that.

And [Zebra](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/) is also not bad, functional and minimalistic, and jQuery based.

A datepicker with the exact design like Skyscanner i think you will not find, so you can see which one of the available ones suits most.

EDIT: Regarding an easy way to add a button to a calendar: see this question "[jquery datepicker adding custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894032/jquery-datepicker-adding-custom-button)"; there is also a jsfiddle referenced in it with an example. Note that this example uses jQuery's Datepicker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matin. They're not bad but I don't see an easy way to add more buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked this out in a roundabout fashion.

**beforeShowDay**
I add the date to each calendar item as a class i.e. "date-YYYYMMDD"
If the date array is populated, add an additional class "preSelectedDay"

**beforeShow**
I dynamically wrap a container with my new buttons around the datepicker, scraping and applying the styles to it from the datepicker

**input.focusin**
I then Add a css class to the datepicker to override inline styles, as this is now handled by the wrapper.

**button.hover**
The button hovers highlight days by manipulating the DOM and adding a "selectedDay" class

**button.click**
The date array then looks for the first and last class "selectedDay" and populates the array by scraping the dates we added earlier "date-YYYYMMDD"

I've created a demo here - http://www.darrencousins.com/lab/jqueryui-datepicker-skyscanner/

(Please ignore the styling)

Cheers