# How to Add custom buttons to jquery datepicker showButtonPanel

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery datepicker adding custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894032/jquery-datepicker-adding-custom-button)

I want to add custom buttons in showButtonPanal which clear or reset Dates selected by user in date range box of jquery DatePicker

My Script is like

```
$(function() {
var fromDate = $("#fromDateId2").datepicker();
var toDate = $("#toDateId2").datepicker();
$('#fromDateId, #toDateId')
        .datepicker({
                    showOn : "both",
                    buttonImage : "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/tp/web/console/include/DatePickerJquery/DatePicker/date.png",
                    buttonImageOnly : true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    beforeShow : customRange,
                    dateFormat : "<%=DateFormatUtil.getDateFormat(true).replaceAll("yyyy", "yy")%>",
                    firstDay : 1,
                    changeFirstDay : true


                });

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894032/jquery-datepicker-adding-custom-button

Comment: Alternative Solution <input type='button' value='Reset' class='reset'/>

$('input.reset').click(function(){
      $('#FORM_ID').each(function(){
        this.reset();
      });

      $('input.hasDatepicker').val('');
    });