# Is there a way to add complex date ranges to jqueryUI DatePicker?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've added Datepickers to several fields on a legacy web app.  One such textbox is an Expiration Date field.  When a user doesn't want something to expire, they set the date to 12/31/9999.  For that reason, I'd like my yearRange in Datepicker to be something like "2012 thru 2022, AND 9999".

It's easy enough to set the range from now to 9999, but that creates a year dropdown w/ thousands of options.  I'd rather just have the 10 options for the next 10 years, and then an 11th option for 9999.

I tried using this yearRange, but Datepicker doesn't seem to understand the comma.  Any ideas?

```
yearRange: "-0:+10,9999"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598850/how-do-you-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-datepicker-in-the-button-panel), I just left my range as "-0:+10", and then I added a "Never" button like this:

```
beforeShow: function( input ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var buttonPane = $(input)
            .datepicker("widget")
            .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");

        var btn = $('<BUTTON class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all">Never</BUTTON>');
        btn
            .unbind("click")
            .bind("click", function () {
                $(input)
                    .datepicker("setDate", new Date(9999,11,31))
                    .datepicker("hide");
            });

        btn.appendTo(buttonPane);

    }, 1 );
}
```

Note - that is the date I had to use to get 12/31/9999 to display correctly.