# Jquery Datetimepicker - add clear button

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

How can i add a clear button to the datetimepicker addon. I was thinking of replacing the done button with a clear button.

Comment: onClose: function(dateText, dp_inst) {
     if (tp_inst.timeDefined === true && $input.val() !== '') {
      tp_inst._updateDateTime(dp_inst);
     }
     if ($.isFunction(o.onClose)) {
      o.onClose.call($input[0], dateText, dp_inst, tp_inst);
     }
    },

Comment: That is the onClose function, so maybe i can alter that in some way to clear the date instead of closing the calendar

Comment: If you mean the jQueryUI one; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598850/how-do-you-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-datepicker-in-the-button-panel

Comment: i added this http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: However i want to add code in the js file so that it can be used everywhere

Comment: nothing seems to work. I tried the solutions found in ^^ but no luck

Comment: so...why does this question have -4, while the linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598850/how-do-you-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-datepicker-in-the-button-panel has +16 votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your button in HTML with a unique ID. In jQuery write this...

```
$("#yourbuttonid").click(function(){
   $("#thedattimepicker").val("");
});
```

On click it will clear the value of whatever element you specify in the function. You can clear more elements by just duplicating the second line of code in the function for more selectors.