# jquery datepicker add button & autoclose: false problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am working on datepicker.js customization, but have some problems here:,(
Could you please give me a clue about what I am doing wrong?

1. I would like to add an additional button (not the button which is named "done" but another button "close" to close the calendar with no action) on the bottom when the calendar is opened(you can click input to open the calendar). The problem I got with this task is it seems a function in "beforeShow" is not working..button is not append
2. when datepicker calendar is opened, I would like the calendar to not auto close when selecting a date. However, I would like to manually close by clicking the "done" button. I tried with "autoclose: false" but .. not working. So, I rather forcefully control the css style to display none and block while.. when after clicking one date, the "active" class is not working for the second click.

Thank you for your time

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
        $(function(){
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy. mm. dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                todayBtn: false, 
                autoclose: true,
                monthNames: ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"],
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                minDate: "+1d",
                showOtherMonths: true,
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
                firstDay:  0, 
                showOtherMonths: false, 
                beforeShow : function(){
                     let thisCalendar = $(this);
                     const btnWrap = thisCalendar.find('.ui-datepicker-buttonpane')
                     btnWrap.append('<span class="">button</span>')
               }
            })
            .focus(function() {
                var thisCalendar = $(this);
                $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("display", "block")
                $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
                    $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("display", "none")
                });
            })
            $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        }); 
    </script>
    <p>Date 1: <input id="datepicker1" class="datepicker" type="text" ></p>
    <p>Date 2: <input id="datepicker2" class="datepicker" type="text" ></p>
    <p>Date 3: <input id="datepicker3" class="datepicker" type="text" ></p>
```

Comment: If this is supposed to be the jQuery UI datepicker - that doesn't _have_ an `afterShow` option, according to its documentation, https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @CBroe I actually change "beforeShow" but still button is not append :,( 
Thank you for the comment tho!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598850/how-do-you-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-datepicker-in-the-button-panel

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following based on [How do you add buttons to a jQuery datepicker in the button panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598850/how-do-you-add-buttons-to-a-jquery-datepicker-in-the-button-panel)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy. mm. dd',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      todayBtn: false,
      autoclose: true,
      //monthNames: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"],
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      minDate: "+1d",
      showOtherMonths: true,
      dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      firstDay: 0,
      showOtherMonths: false,
      beforeShow: function(inp, inst) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          var btnWrap = $(inp)
            .datepicker("widget")
            .find(".ui-datepicker-buttonpane");
          btnWrap.append('<span class="">button</span>');
        }, 1);
      }
    })
    .focus(function() {
      var thisCalendar = $(this);
      $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
      var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      thisCalendar.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("display", "block")
      $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").css("display", "none")
      });
    })
  $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->

<p>Date 1: <input id="datepicker1" class="datepicker" type="text"></p>
<p>Date 2: <input id="datepicker2" class="datepicker" type="text"></p>
<p>Date 3: <input id="datepicker3" class="datepicker" type="text"></p>
```